# Extract html source code from a dynamic page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making a site where the user drops by drag and drop elements. I would like to know how I can capture after that:

I need Capture Code HTML from `<div id="frame">` 
Thank.

Pd: The important thing is that I can not refresh the page because I lose the changes.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>   
    <div class="section">
      <div class="menu">
      </div>    
      <div id="frame" class="ui-sortable">
      </div>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because poster is asking "give me the codez" and should probably hire a developer if that's what they need

Comment: Im sorry, but I tried with jquery, php Dom and can not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Use ZeroClipboard and change line 998

event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", textContent); for

event.clipboardData.setData("text/html", textContent);

```
<button class="btnCopyToClipboard" data-clipboard-target="frame" data-clipboard-text="Default text">Copiar texto</button>
        <script src="js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function (){
            var clip = new ZeroClipboard($(".btnCopyToClipboard"), {
              moviePath: '("/js/ZeroClipboard.swf")' // ruta donde se encuentra el plugin
            });
            clip.on('load', function(client){
           });
           clipboardData.setData("text/html", htmlContent);
           clip.on('complete', function(client, args){
             this.style.display = 'none'; // "this" is the element that was clicked
             alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + args.text );
           });

           clip.on('mouseover', function(client){
           });

           clip.on('mouseout', function(client){
          });
          clip.on('mousedown', function(client){
         });
           clip.on('mouseup', function(client){
           });
       });
   </script>
```